# Как создать 2 одинаковых TreeView с одинаковым содержимым ItemsSource программно?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как создать 2 одинаковых TreeView с одинаковым содержимым ItemsSource программно?

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что есть метод клонирования, но есть неплохой вариант:

---

Попробуй воспользоваться классами XamlReader и XamlWriter. Т.е. сериализовать твой контрол в строку, потом создать дубликат из этой строки, а потом просто программно добавить привязку ItemsSource. Должно работать, и не только с TreeView.
Ну есть также и VisualBrush, но это скорее не этот вопрос